# NSManagedObject, cascade delete more than one relationship

Tags: core-data

Is it possible to get Core Data cascade delete to delete objects more than one level deep?

ObjectA has an NSSet of ObjectB, ObjectB has an NSSet of ObjectC

When I delete ObjectA, I want ObjectB and ObjectC to be deleted.

I set the relationship of ObjectA<->>ObjectB to cascade, and the relationship of ObjhectB<->>ObjectC to cascade but no dice. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh Danny Boy, code rules. It is very difficult to help you without seeing what you are exactly doing. Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you described it, these are one-way relationships. So this answer reflects that case. I think that if you set the relationships like this

```
object a <-->> object b <-->> object c
```

(I use <-->> to illustrate one-to-many and many-to-one, since you describe the 
   relationship of a to b where b is a set.)

you will have object b depending on the existence of object a and object c depending on the existence of object b.

Then if object a disappears, then object b sees that the relationship is not fulfilled and will delete itself. Then object c will see that the relationship is not fulfilled and delete itself.

As it is written in your question, object b does not have a relationship to object a, so it is not expecting anything with respect to object a.

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. I have updated my question to reflect the inverse relationships. They are indeed one to many. The issue still exists.